# GPRS/Data only starts after reset

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, gprs

I have Karbonn A9, Android 2.3.6.
The GPRS/Data does not switch on occasionally, but once I reboot the phone I can start it. 
After deactivating GPRS/Data I have to reboot the phone get either data or GPRS to connect again. What could be causing this?

Comment: Try airplane mode, is can appear to be a faster cure than reboot.

Comment: Thanks, switching to airplane mode & comae back to normal helped.

Comment: Firmware upgrade? BTW just noticed... (Out of curiousity is it GSM in India? Or is it CDMA?)

Comment: Both CDMA and GSM phones are available. But GSM is more common.

Answer (score 0):

Backup your data and factory reset your device. If problem is intact, its firmware issue. Fixing it isn't easier than flashing new ROM.

The best way to work around: Disconnect Mobile Data by renaming APN. No need to factory reset or to flash new ROM. You don't need to rename APN manually. Install [Widgetsoid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jim2) and use its mobile data toggle widget. In settings, make sure toggle method is APN renaming. Done!